# The term used for short form of a word

Tags: single-word-requests

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the term for neglectful spelling of words such as “you” as “u”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14633/what-is-the-term-for-neglectful-spelling-of-words-such-as-you-as-u)

what is the proper word to say  words that is being used as in chat.eg:- like = lyk. the = da, etc.
example sentence is given below.

I am going 2 dat guy 2 say abt it.